# Save a file as PDF on download

Tags: c#, .net

I have a web application that dynamically generates RTF documents based on user input. Once generated, the documents can be downloaded by the user.

I would like the documents to be downloaded as PDF files instead of RTF.

How can I programaticaly do that?

Comment: You need to convert rtf to pdf or create a pdf directly (instead of making an rtf). There are a lot of 3rd libraries like [iTextsharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/), [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com) and others which can do this.

Comment: What have you tried? (Specifically what PDF generation tools have you looked at, and why can't they handle this?)